# nginx proxied redirects use the port number of the proxy, not the host

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm setting up a web/app/db stack, and the nginx proxy configuration isn't working the way I thought it would.

so here is an example of the stack...the url of the application is:
https://testapp.com

here is the nginx config:

```
   server {
   listen       8886;
   server_name  _;
   root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
   include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

   #ELB
   if ($http_user_agent = 'ELB-HealthChecker/2.0') {
    return 200 working;
   }

   #HTTP to HTTPS
   if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
   location / {
        set $proxy_upstream_name "testapp.com";
        port_in_redirect off;
        proxy_pass         http://internal-alb.amazonaws.com:8083/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;}
```

The app is proxied to an internal AWS alb, and it forwards it to a single (at this point) application server.

I'm able to get the site to serve.  However, the application creates a redirect on login, and I get the following response.

```
Request URL:https://testapp.com/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 
Remote Address:34.192.444.29:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
content-language:en-US
content-length:0
date:Mon, 11 Sep 2017 18:35:34 GMT
location:http://testapp.com:8083/testCode
server:openresty/1.11.2.5
status:302
```

The redirect fails because it's being served on 443, not 8083.

For some reason the app or the proxy isn't updating the port as it doing it's reverse proxy thing, so that the redirect has the proxied port NOT the actual application port 443.

What do I need to do with nginx config to get it to redirect correctly.

thanks.
myles.

Comment: This is a AJAX call or a normal post call?

Comment: Try adding `proxy_redirect http://internal-alb.amazonaws.com:8083/ https://testapp.com;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal behaviour of the nginx is to rewrite the upstream address to the address the page was served from.  It looks like instead of using your upstream address (http://internal-alb.amazonaws.com:8083/), your app is responding using a mixture of the two (http://testapp.com:8083).  You can either change the app behaviour, or, to fix it at the nginx level, can use the [proxy_redirect directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

I'm reasonably sure the directive to fix this is `proxy_redirect http://testapp.com:8083/ https://testapp.com/;`